# Create every new csrf token laravel api router axios post

Tags: laravel, redis, axios, token, csrf

I am working on Laravel/Vue project.
I have some axios posts with crsf token.
But when I set SESSION_DRIVER to `cookie`, I got `419 error` with CSRF token mismatch for these axios posts.
SESSION_DRIVER is `redis` or `file`, this is working well.

Client sends the one csrf token

```
if(!window.axios) {
    window.axios = require("axios");

    window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
    };
}
```

```
axios
    .post("/api/shopping/getCartInfo", {
        cartid: self.cartid,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        self.cartQuantity = response.data.cart.qty;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
                    
    });
```

But backend for every post request receives different token.
So 419 errors happen.

```
public function getCartInfo(Request $request)
{
    \Log::info($request->session()->token()); // not same csrf token from client
    try {
        $cart = Cart::find($request->cartid);

        return response()->json(['result' => 'success', 'cart' => $cart]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['result' => 'failed', 'error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

The problem is to receive different token every time for every post request.
Who can help me?
Thanks.

I tried axios post request with csrf token, I want to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check, in your `config\cors.php` file, that the 'path' and 'allowed_origins' values are properly set?

It's content should look something like this:

```
   'paths' => [
      'api/*',
      'login',
      'logout',
      'register',
      'user/password',
      'forgot-password',
      'reset-password',
      'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
      'user/profile-information',
      'email/verification-notification',
   ],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
```